# How to protect a Language Shop in Shopware?

Tags: .htaccess, shopware

I have a Shopware shop with the following Domain:

```
myshop.tld
```

Now I have created a so called »Language Shop« on the same Domain which is accessible via:

```
myshop.tld/en
```

How to protect **only** the new Language Shop (myshop.tld/en) with .htaccess and .htpasswd?

Comment: You have a shop selling languages? Wow! Great! What new languages are in stock 2021? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in the webserver configuration (`Location` does not work in the `.htaccess`)

```
<Location /en>
  Require valid-user
  AuthType basic
  AuthName "Protected shop"
  AuthUserFile /your/path/.htpasswd
</Location>
```

See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/580067/288568

If you don't have access to the web server vhost configuration, you can use something like

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/en/.*" DENY
```

*edit*

Use

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/en.*" DENY
```

to match also the homepage.

in the `.htaccess` to define an env variable and DENY access based on this.

I recommend to use the web-server configuration (if possible) because it's easier to read.

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution. :)

I tried the .htaccess solution coz I do not have access to webserer configuration. The .htaccess solution works fine... but the homepage e.g. myshop.tld/en is nevertheless accessible. It only works for all other pages, e.g. myshop.tld/en/whatever! Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: remove the final "/"

`SetEnvIf Request_URI "/en.*"`

Comment: Feel free to post your full solution

Comment: Did it work? You might want to accept the answer and vote if it helped you :-D?