# Serve webpage in firewalled ip through portal machine

Tags: php, apache, firewall

I have house.dynamicdnsservice.com pointing to my house IP.

My firewall allows incoming https connections to go to 192.168.0.22, where I put google oauth login. That part is working fine. I'm able to access my house from anywhere and run the google login.

My next step is to provide access to logged in users to a webpage in IP 192.168.0.34. The firewall does NOT allow that IP to be accessed from the WAN side.

How can I use the .22 machine to serve/redirect/portal the firewalled .34 server? (after logging in, of course)

I'm running ubuntu/apache/php on both machines.

Comment: What is the purpose of splitting the services between two machines? Why not move the oauth to 34, or the web content to 22?

Comment: Eventually I'd like to have access to other machines in my LAN (like my NAS) so I thought using 1 machine as entry point would be better for security. Also 34 is a raspberry with a prepackaged software.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to set up the .22 machine as a [reverse proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html#proxy)

[Difference between proxy server and reverse proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224664/difference-between-proxy-server-and-reverse-proxy-server)

Some information about handling authentication pass-thru for an apache reverse  proxy: [Apache2 Reverse Proxy to an end-point that requires BasicAuth but want to hide this from user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567814/apache2-reverse-proxy-to-an-end-point-that-requires-basicauth-but-want-to-hide-t)

[Squid can also be configured to manage this.](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ReverseProxy)

[A walk-thru of this kind of setup](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/protect-your-ports-reverse-proxy)