# Basic-style auth with mod_auth_openidc

Tags: mod-auth-openidc

Is there a way to configure mod_auth_openidc to act something like basic auth rather than redirecting to the auth provider (Okta, in my case) for login?

I'm setting up mod_auth_openidc on a reverse proxy but I'm protecting APIs that are accessed by services that can't handle anything more complicated than basic auth.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to statically add a header that provides the required Basic authentication information as documented in [Apache2 Reverse Proxy to an end-point that requires BasicAuth but want to hide this from user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567814/apache2-reverse-proxy-to-an-end-point-that-requires-basicauth-but-want-to-hide-t)

So it would look something like:

`RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ=="`

Comment: But that gives me one username/password for everyone that consumes my site.  I'd still like the APIs to log in - multiple apps, one account per app, accessing one endpoint.

Comment: you can use that header in a specific context such as a Location, Directory and virtual host